# Capacitor App plugins break when setting server to https

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I’m working on an Ionic App using Capacitor. Everything has been going well until I needed to change the dev server to use https.
However, setting this https server seems to break the App capacitor plugin @capacitor/app. and this error appears

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: "App" plugin is not implemented on android`

in **capacitor.config.ts** :

```
server: {
  url: "https://test.tuneps.tn",
  androidScheme: "https",
  cleartext: true
},
```

MainActivity :

```
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {}
```

i tried to upgrade the @capacitor/app to the latest version and changed the Main Activity file few times with no result.

Note : everything works well on http .

Valid certificate :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server certificates are not valid, capacitor will not be able to inject the plugins JavaScript code and they will not work.

Comment: Certificate is valid

Comment: The device seems to disagree with you. It also happens if there are problems with the intermediate certificates.

Comment: If the URL you provided is the URL you are testing (`https://test.tuneps.tn/portail`), chrome says the certificate is not valid.

Comment: I just added a screenshot confirming the certificate validity . am i missing something ?

Comment: Check the url on https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker or https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://test.tuneps.tn/ or similar ssl validation services, both of them show issues.

Comment: Thank you. We're currently looking into the issue, and I'll keep you updated if it solves the problem or not.